# MVVM light Page Navigation Outside ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I'm trying to Invoke `NavigateTo` in Windows 8.1 Universal app outside of the wiew model. I already tried:

```
var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

await dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    async () => await NavigateToRegistrationPage()
);
```

Resulting with exception thrown

> Object reference not set to instance of object.

I also tried Using Messenger to invoke navigation form ViewModel via messenger message:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<MessengerEvents.NavigateToRegistrationPage>(
    new MessengerEvents.NavigateToRegistrationPage()
);

Public LoginViewModel //...

MessengerInstance.Register<MessengerEvents.NavigateToRegistrationPage>(
    this,
    (message) => GoToRegistrationPage()
);
```

Doesn't work either.

> Error has been thrown by the target of invocation

I cant invoke navigation directly in viewmodel *(checked without messenger called directly from the view model works perfectly)* as navigation is performed in response to server message.

```
private void GoToRegistrationPage() 
{
    NavigationService.NavigateTo(ResourceService.CHOOSE_REGISTRATION_PAGE); 
}
```

Comment: Depending on how you are using MVVM-Light, there should be an IOC container from which you can request the current instance of the navigationservice. And use that to do the same actual navigation as inside your viewmodels

Comment: `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();` would be the code most likely

Comment: @Depechie When i tried this i checked that i get the object but "currentPageKey" is null" I have this page in CreateNavigationService      navigationService.Configure(ResourceService.CHOOSE_LOGIN_PAGE, typeof(LoginPage)); still no idea how to solve it instance.currentPageKey threw exception of type System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Hmm a bit unclear what is going on just by reading this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I tried to grab dispatcher from MVVM Locator, moved dispatcher to app.xaml.cs and works perfectly